# Why my <li> doesn't get "active"?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Just a little problem with my custom bootstrap carousel..
My `<li>` doesn't get class `active`...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".carousel").carousel({
    interval: 2000
  });
  $(".carousel").on("slid", function() {
    var to_slide;
    to_slide = $(".carousel-item.active").attr("data-slide-no");
    $(".myCarousel-target.active").removeClass("active");
    $(".carousel-indicators [data-slide-to=" + to_slide + "]").addClass("active");
  });
  $(".myCarousel-target").on("click", function() {
    $(this).preventDefault();
    $(".carousel").carousel(parseInt($(this).attr("data-slide-to")));
    $(".myCarousel-target.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

and my fiddle [fiddle boot carousel](http://jsfiddle.net/pj1t22my/)

Comment: Well, if i am not wrong i don't see any element with class `.myCarousel-target`!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pj1t22my/6/

Comment: seems not work with auto slide..

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to not having a class called `.myCarousel-target` and also for having a `preventDefault()` when there is no default event to run on a normal `li`.

Try this JS out:

```
$(".carousel-indicators li").on("click", function() {
  $(".carousel").carousel(parseInt($(this).attr("data-slide-to")));
  $(".carousel-indicators li.active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

[JSFiddle of working example](https://jsfiddle.net/pj1t22my/1/)

Comment: Hmm, will look into it a bit more

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pj1t22my/4/)**. I have reformatted the block `$(".carousel").on("slid", function() {` as below.

```
$(".carousel").on("slid.bs.carousel", function () {
    var act = $('.carousel-indicators li.active').next();
    if (act[0] == undefined) {
        act = $('.carousel-indicators li:first-child');
    }
    $('.carousel-indicators li').removeClass("active");
    act.addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: seems to be the solution that best approach but when click the "li" no longer corresponds to its "slide"

Comment: @angelilo_ : **[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pj1t22my/7/)** change `$(".carousel").on("slid.bs.carousel", function () {` into `$(".carousel").on("slid.bs.carousel slid", function () {`

Comment: I realize that this does not work unfortunately. When I click on a number, it changes the display order and nothing is ...

http://jsfiddle.net/pj1t22my/7/